# WebView doesn't load everytime

Tags: android, firebase-realtime-database, android-webview

The WebView loads PDF's which are fetched from Firebase Database.

Once I pressed back from the WebView and then Open the WebView Activity, nothing loads. Simply a White Blank Screen.

Here is my Activity Code :

```
public class ShowPdfActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_show_pdf);
        webView = findViewById(R.id.webView);

        ShowContent();


    }

    private void ShowContent() {
        webView.setWebChromeClient(new WebChromeClient());

        webView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
        webView.getSettings().setBuiltInZoomControls(true);
        webView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient() {
            @Override
            public void onPageStarted(WebView view, String url, Bitmap favicon) {
                super.onPageStarted(view, url, favicon);

                progressDialog.setTitle("Please Wait");
                progressDialog.setMessage("Previewing your Content ..");
                progressDialog.setIcon(R.mipmap.ic_launcher_round);
                progressDialog.setCanceledOnTouchOutside(false);
                progressDialog.show();

            }

            @Override
            public void onPageFinished(WebView view, String url) {
                super.onPageFinished(view, url);
                progressDialog.dismiss();
            }

        });
        webView.postDelayed(new Runnable() {

            @Override
            public void run() {

                String url = "";
                try {
                    url = URLEncoder.encode(Pdf_data, "UTF-8"); 
                } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }

                webView.loadUrl("http://drive.google.com/viewerng/viewer?embedded=true&url=" + url);
            }
        }, 400);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onResume() {
        super.onResume();
        ShowContent();
    }

    public void destroyWebView() {

        rel11.removeAllViews();
        webView.clearHistory();
        webView.clearCache(true);
        webView.loadUrl("about:blank");
        webView.onPause();
        webView.removeAllViews();
        webView.destroyDrawingCache();
        webView.pauseTimers();
        webView.destroy();
        webView = null;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onDestroy() {
        super.onDestroy();
        Log.e("On Destroy here", "here");
        destroyWebView();
    }
}
```

How can the Blank Screen be fixed, so that the WebView loads the Contents everytime and not after I clear the App's Data.

Comment: Where are you getting data from Firebase?

Comment: Data is being sent from another activity to this Activity using intent,getStringExtra("PDFS")